# Correlating log messages within scope

Tags: c#, log4net, trace, nlog

I would like to correlate logging messages using a logging scope. I'm looking for an implementation for log4net, NLog, or System.Diagnostics.Trace. Below is a basic implementation that demonstrates the concept. The output from the program is this:

```
First level: Logging in the run method
First level: Logging one level down
Second scope: Another message
First level: Back from scope
```

Is there a more robust/general/proven/easy-to-use-with-some-framework version of what is done below?

```cs
class Program
{
    private static readonly Log Log = new Log();

    private static void Main()
    {
        using (new LoggingScope("First level"))
        {
            Run();
        }
    }

    private static void Run()
    {
        Log.Info("Logging in the run method");
        Run2();
    }

    private static void Run2()
    {
        Log.Info("Logging one level down");
        using (new LoggingScope("Second scope"))
        {
            Log.Info("Another message");
        }

        Log.Info("Back from scope");
    }
}

internal class Log
{
    static Log()
    {
        CurrentScope = new Stack<string>();
    }

    private static Stack<string> CurrentScope { get; set; }

    public static void PushScope(string name)
    {
        CurrentScope.Push(name);
    }

    public static void PopScope()
    {
        CurrentScope.Pop();
    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {
        var currentScope = CurrentScope.Count == 0 ? string.Empty : CurrentScope.Peek();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", currentScope, message);
    }
}

internal class LoggingScope : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public LoggingScope(string id)
    {
        _name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Log.PushScope(id);
        CallContext.SetData(_name, id);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Log.PopScope();
        CallContext.FreeNamedDataSlot(_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for nested diagnostic context (NDC):

```
    Log.Info("Logging one level down");
    using(ThreadContext.Stacks["NDC"].Push( requestid))
    {
        Log.Info("Another message");
    }
    Log.Info("Back from scope");
```

To get the scope in your log output use %property{NDC} in your conversion pattern:

```
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
```

[log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks (404)](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.ThreadContext.Stacks.html)

[log4net.NDC (deprecated) (404)](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.NDC.html)

Answer (score 1):

NLog has the Nested Diagnostics Logical Context (NDLC) that can be used like this:

```
using (NLog.NestedDiagnosticsLogicalContext.Push("First Level"))
{
    Run();
}
```

And you can extract the NLog scopes using [${ndlc}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/NDLC-Layout-Renderer) in the `Layout`-output.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Extension Logging has the `ILogger.BeginScope()` method.

That you can use like this:

```
using (_logger.BeginScope("First Level"))
{
   _logger.LogDebug("Logon from {0}", request.UserId);
}
```

And you can extract the NLog scopes using [${ndlc}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/NDLC-Layout-Renderer) in the `Layout`-output.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging